# My app is not recognizing a library imported inside another custom library

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-library

I am new to android development.

I created a simple custom button library with rounded button that I'm using in another custom library. I used file->import->module->myCustomButtonLibrary to my another custom library.

That custom library is recognizing the button library fine along with all of its functionality.

Now I'm using that another library in the a app. I imported that the library same way, and the app is recognizing all the functionality of the other library but it is unable to access class from the button library.

This is the error I get

```
Cannot access class 'com.example.CustomButton'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

Application's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.screenpatterns"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation project(':screenpattern')    }
```

custom library's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27



    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation project(':custombutton')

}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

As you can see screen pattern library already includes custom button library.

any help is appreciated
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `build.gradle`.

Comment: @ADM added build.gradle